# Android loaders vs Handlers

Tags: java, android

The `loaders` help in asynchronously getting the data from a data source. We can achieve the same effect using `Handlers`, where we can kick off a thread or execute a Executor and can fetch the data in that thread. Once data is fetched, we can update the UI using the UI handler Message mechanism. 
Then why do go for coding the complex loaders when we can achieve the same by using `Handlers`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loaders were introduced to make it easier in implementing correct data loading on android platform. This means:

- doing all the heavy stuff on background thread
- safely introducing loaded data in UI
- caching of data, this means improving speed
- loaders can live outside the Activity lifecycle, so if you have config change then your data is not destroyed
- loaders will be reloaded once your data store changes

using Handlers,Executors, or AsyncTasks does not take into account all above points. Your will have to manage this by yourself, and this is the work android developers put into Loaders implementation.

Ie. using AsyncTask for loading some data requires you to watch out for screen rotations, ie. you must somehow retain reference to your AsyncTask that might still do something in background once you activity is recreated due to screen rotation.

Comment: I am aware that AsyncTask cannot take care of screen orientation changes, since it is tied up with the Activity. But in case where we dont use the AsyncTask rather invoke our own background thread from the ui thread will our thread be restarted on screen orientation change?

Comment: @SumitTrehan well, you can start a Thread and post updates using Handler, but this doesn't make life easier, because this way is error-prone. You have to check if Activity is alive, you can easily get memory leak, etc. Thread will not be restarted unless you care about it somehow.

Comment: Doing it all by yourself with AsyncTask is complicated, you need to implement lots of additional code that will take care of all the cases which might break your app causing crashes. On the other hand understanding Loaders also requires deep knowledge on how they work - othen you need to look into sources - just take a look at this post: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html. Conclusion is that managing data loading under android is difficult to make correct. I suppose it is easier if you have data in sqlite database or ContentProvider and use cursors etc.

Comment: @MightySeal I got your point regrading Activity may not be alive. However how can posting the results can result into memory leaks?

Comment: @marcinj Thanks for pointing to the link. Hoping to get internal details.

Comment: @SumitTrehan if you hold a reference to Activity. There are 2 different things: Activity as an app entity and Activity as java Object. For instance activity goes to background and gc can easily collect it. When Activity starts again it may be a different object. System will pass Bundle savedInstanceState with the date you have stored. But if Thread holds Activity's reference gc will not collect it and that's the point where the party starts.

Comment: Apart from that, you can also throttle and it increases code readability.